# Schema for Json Loader?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a json document. Something like a document below.

```
{"sick":["sick","sickness"], "typhoid":["thyphoid A","thyphoid B","typhoid C"]}
```

How do i load this document in Pig using JsonLoader. This is what i tried:

```
A = LOAD 'd' USING JsonLoader('key:map[]');
```

The output i get is:

```
Input paths to process : 1
()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native JsonLoader for pig does not handle nested arrays well.

For loading complex JSON with nested arrays you will have a much easier time if you set up the Elephant-Bird (https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/) JsonLoader. You can then do something like the following:

```
REGISTER '/path/to/elephant-bird.jar';
B = LOAD '/path/to/your/jsonfile.json' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad');
```

The -nestedLoad tag will handle any nested JSON arrays. You may also need to register the json_simple library for this to work. Also, I would recommend looking through the examples posted in the Github repository to get better acquainted with the format of the output.